# Couchbase administrative password vs. cluster admin password

Tags: couchbase

For Couchbase v4.1, I'm confused about the two. Questions:

- Are they the same thing?
- Both are using the default administrative username as `Administrator`, correct? We should never change that?
- When I installed couchbase-server in a fresh node and then join an existing cluster, it skips setting the server admin password for the current node and asks to enter the admin password of the existing cluster. Does that mean the new node share the same administrative with the cluster?
- If I use [cbreset_password](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/cli/cbreset_password-tool.html#cbreset_password_tool) tool to reset the admin password of a node in an existing cluster, will it impact other nodes? Or I should never do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes. Think of a single node as a cluster of one.
- If you can change it, you should. Good security practice
- When you add a node to an existing cluster, the new node gets the config from the existing cluster, password and all.
- If you change the password on one node of the cluster, you are actually changing it for the entire cluster and all nodes that are a part of that cluster. It is a cluster wide setting.